# Jest global functions and TypeScript type definition in a Lerna project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have the following lerna project structure:

```
/
  packages/
    package-A/
      src/
        __tests__/
      tsconfig.json
      jest.config.js
  tsconfig.json
  jest.base.js
  jest.setup.js
  jest.d.ts
```

I'm trying to add global functions to jest - this works but the type definition is not recognized and I get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'myFunc'` for example. If I add `// @ts-ignore`, then `myFunc` *is* defined. So here are the configs:

```
// jest.base.js
module.exports = {
   ...,
   setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/../../jest.setup.js'],
}

// jest.config.js (for a given package)
module.exports = {
  ...require('../../jest.setup.js'),
}

// jest.setup.js
global.myFunct = () => console.log('I am called');

// tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "include": [ "./jest.d.ts" ]
}

// jest.d.ts
declare global {
  namespace jest {
    const myFunct: () => void;
  }
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong and why the type-definition is not recognized by TS.